# GraphQL query not returning result with id argument

Tags: reactjs, neo4j, graphql, grandstack

I have a basic graph set up on Neo4j that contains some movies and I'm using GraphQL to connect to it from a React App. I am testing some queries using the GraphQL playground before adding them to my React App and I've run into an issue when passing an ID type argument. Each of my `mem` nodes has the following schema (as displayed in the GraphQL playground documents):

```
Mem(
memID: ID
mem: String
date: _Neo4jDateInput
memType: String
emoji: String
pictures: String
personID: Int
placeID: Int
favourite: Boolean
public: Boolean
_id: String
first: Int
offset: Int
orderBy: [_MemOrdering]
filter: _MemFilter
): [Mem]
```

When I query the graph, I can pass arguments, such as the `mem` string to return a particular node. For example, the following query:

```
{
  Mem(mem: "The Empire Strikes Back") {
        memID
        mem
        favourite
  }
}
```

Returns the following data from that node:

```
{
  "data": {
    "Mem": [
      {
        "memID": "180",
        "mem": "The Empire Strikes Back",
        "favourite": false
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However, when I try to pass a `memID` as an argument, as follows:

```
{
  Mem(memID: 180) {
        memID
        mem
        favourite
  }
}
```

I get the following response instead of it returning the node's data:

```
{
  "data": {
    "Mem": []
  }
}
```

I'm relatively new to graphQL and feel like I'm missing something basic, but I've searched the documentation and done a lot of Googling around and can't find the solution. I want to be able to query my graph using `memID` as an argument and just can't get it to work.

**UPDATE**

The documentation states that memID is a scalar and I just can't figure out how to express it in the query. It states it can be expresses as a number or a string but neither have worked:

[image]

Comment: why not `  Mem(memID: "180") {` ?

Comment: I'm not THAT new to graphQL! 

Comment: `memID` not included in top level Query (schema - `type Query {
  Mem( .XXXX.`) ?

Comment: I tried that and still no joy I'm afraid! This is a real puzzle...